# Demonstration of complete system of residual classes. (Demonstração de sistema completo de classes resíduais.)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Which step I have to follow to solve:
>
> Let $ \{a_1, ..., a_m\} $ a complete system of residues modulo $m$, show that $a\in\mathbb{N}$, then $ \{a_1 + a, ..., a_m + a\} $ is a complete residue system module $ m $.

$$$$

> Quais os passo tenho de seguir para resolver:
>
> Seja ${a_1,...,a_m}$ um sistema completo de resíduos módulo $m$, mostre que se $a\in\mathbb{N}$
>   , então ${a_1+a,...,a_m+a}$ é um sistema completo de resíduos módulo $m$.
>
> Eu tentei fazer assim.
>
> Demonstração:
>
> Se $\{a_1,...,a_m\}$ é um sistema completo de resídulos módulo $m$, então
>   $$a_i\not\equiv a_j \pmod m$$ com $1\leq i<j\leq m$, Então temos que $$a_i+a\not\equiv a_j+a \pmod m$$ o que nos diz que $\{a_1+a,...,a_m+a\}$ é um sistema completo de resíduos módulo $m$.
>   $\Box$

Comment: $$\{a_1,...,a_m\}$$ then(então) $$a_1=0\pmod m\\a_2=1\pmod m\\...\\a_m=m-1\pmod m\\$$?????????

Answer (score 1):

It suffices to show that if $1\le k<\ell\le m$, then $a_k+a\not\equiv a_\ell+a\pmod m$. That shows that the integers $a_1+a,\ldots,a_m+1$ are all in different residue classes, and since there are exactly $m$ residue classes, the set $\{a_1+a,\ldots,a_m+a\}$ must contain one member from each class, making it a complete residue system modulo $m$.

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you, but would like a written statement, to better understand how to write. I made one, could post it, but would like to see it a bit more elegant. Could you help me with this?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: If you edit your question to include it, I’ll comment on it and suggest any improvements that I think ought to be made.

Comment: Okay, I did what you asked.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: If I understand the Portuguese correctly: If $\{a_1,\ldots,a_m\}$ is a complete residue system modulo $m$, then $a_i\not\equiv a_j\pmod m$ for $1\le i<j\le m$. Then we have that $a_i+a\not\equiv a_j+a\pmod m$, ... . I’d repeat ‘for $1\le i<j\le m$’ at that point, but otherwise it looks fine.

Comment: My teacher said: "You proved that it is a system correctly.
Remains to show that the system is complete. "

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: Oops. I was working so hard to follow the Portuguese that I didn’t notice that you left that part out; it’s the part of my answer starting with *and since there are*. I should have noticed; I’m sorry.

Comment: The language barrier is not making me understand.

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: Not understand my comment, or not understand that part of the answer?

Comment: M. Sott I do not understand the second part of the answer!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior: You know that congruence mod $m$ is an equivalence relation on $\Bbb Z$. It has exactly $m$ equivalence classes: the integers congruent to $0$ mod $m$ form one class, the integers congruent to $1$ mod $m$ form another, and so on, up to the integers congruent to $m-1$. A complete residue system is a set $R$ of $m$ integers that contains exactly one integer from each residue class. Since no two members of $R$ are in the same class, no two members of $R$ are congruent mod $m$. If $n\in\Bbb Z$, then $n$ is in one of the $m$ residue classes, so $n$ is in the same class as some ...

Comment: ... $r\in R$. But that means that $n\equiv r\pmod m$, so every integer is congruent mod $m$ to some member of $R$, and $R$ is therefore complete.